# Change Commit Message Without Rebasing?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict, git-rewrite-history

I have a relatively old branch (2 weeks). After changes, I commit my code (with the message `git commit -m "ABC commit"`) and then pull the `main` branch. I resolved a few conflicts and merge by using `git add .` and then `git commit -m "Merged Main"`.

Now I am trying to change the second last commit message from *ABC commit* to *XYZ commit*. For that, I used the below command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Then in the editor, I changed `pick` to `reword` and after saving the file, changed the commit message. Now when I save the file, git starts rebasing and shows conflicts like

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in [redacted]
Auto-merging [redacted]
error: could not apply 91[redacted]
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort"
Could not apply 911[redacted]

PC@DESKTOP-15[redacted]
```

Since my branch is 2 weeks old, it rebasing all those changes since then, which I already have merged in my current branch.

Is there a simpler way to change the second last commit message without resolving others' code conflicts and rebasing?

*Note: I haven't pushed my local branch.*

Comment: Should be. Could change things by making a new commit and using git-replace followed by git-filter-repo. With the usual caveat that git-filter-repo is destructive.

Comment: To be clear- only two commits need to be modified: your "ABC commit" and the merge commit? So the simple answer is to checkout your commit, amend it, and redo the merge. But the issue is you don't wish to redo the merge conflict resolution? In that case, @Guildenstern's idea should work. If the message "ABC commit" is unique in the entire history you can even just pass the `--replace-message` option and it should only rewrite that commit and the merge commit.

Comment: Since you haven't push yet, I would squash the branch and use the desired commit message. Is there any strong reason to not squash it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the commit messages or the commit metadata then
you don’t really need to “replay” the commits, as git-rebase(1)
does. And if you don’t try to replay the commits then you won’t need to
redo the merge conflicts.

You want the same snapshot as your current merge. So you can reuse it
with git-commit-tree(1).

The procedure:

1. Record both the commit message and the *tree* of the merge commit
2. Go back one commit and change the commit message
3. Make a new commit with:

   - Your amended commit as the first parent
   - `origin/main` as the second parent
   - The tree of the original merge commit
4. Fast-forward to the new commit

I’ll assume a history like this one:

```
... --- b --- M (HEAD, main)
... --- c --/ (origin/main)
```

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Assuming that you are on `main` and on the merge commit
merge_tree=$(git rev-parse HEAD^{tree})
git log --format=%B -1 > merge-message.txt
# Checkout “ABC commit”
git reset --hard HEAD^1
git commit --amend --no-edit -m'XYZ commit'
# The two merge parents
amended=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
main_commit=$(git rev-parse origin/main)
new_merge=$(git commit-tree -F merge-message.txt -p $amended -p $main_commit $merge_tree)
git merge --ff-only $new_merge
# Cleanup
rm merge-message.txt
```

[test with](https://pastebin.com/XnECNBMY)